# "Edit removed during grace period" is not translatable in a couple of contexts

Tags: bug, localization, grace-period, russian-stackoverflow

The text "Edit removed during grace period" is out of translation engine for a couple of situations:

- [on the post edit page:](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/937669/edit)

  > [image: post edit]
- [on the profile activity tab revision subtab](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/%C3%A4l%D1%91x%C3%B6l%C3%BCt?tab=activity&sort=revisions)

  > [image: profile]
- On the same time the text is translated on the [post revisions page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/937669/revisions):

  > [image: post revisions]

Link to the original string in traducir: https://ru.traducir.win/string/458