# Translation of "appended answer {id} as supplemental" is not used on profile page

Tags: bug, profile-page, localization, grace-period

Translation of [*"appended answer {id} as supplemental"*](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/9549) is not used on [profile page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%B1?tab=activity&sort=revisions):

> [image: appended answer]

At the same time all is fine on the [post revision page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1256137/revisions):

> [image: revision page with no translation]

It seems that the same issue exists for "[Edit removed during grace period]" according to the recent bug report on ruSO.meta: [Не переведено [Edit removed during grace period] в списке правок в профиле](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11470/176217)

Found the related post ["Edit removed during grace period" is not translatable in a couple of contexts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323043/339911) on MSE itself.

Comment: For context: moderators have the ability to convert an answer into an edit to the question, i.e. delete it and at the same time edit its contents into the question. That's the feature being used here.

Comment: There's something similar going on at [PT SO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sBtl.png); it doesn't say "Votar contra".

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog thanks for your comment, don’t hesitate to edit the question to make it more clear.